# Border with equal sizes on all 4 sides of JTextpane

Tags: java, swing, border, jtextpane

I am setting a `createLineborder` to my `JTextPane`. But the border lines are little different in right-end and bottom of `JTextpane` when compared to Left-end and top of `TextPane`. I searched in net and I found that it is the default behavior of `lineborder`. So can anyone please tell me that is there any border which gives equal lines sizes in all 4 sides?

Hi I cannot put my code as it is very huge. So just putting a sample code here.
JPanel panel;
    JTextPane pane;

```
public BorderedTextPane() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    pane = new JTextPane();
    panel = new JPanel(null);
    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(null);
    innerPanel.setBounds(50,50,300,400);
    pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    pane.setSize(new Dimension(innerPanel.getWidth(),innerPanel.getHeight()));
    innerPanel.add(pane);
    panel.add(innerPanel);
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

This could be clearly seen if you zoom the textpane or when you save it on a file. Below image would explain it in better way. Compare the left and right lines.
    [image]

Comment: question is JTextPane placed in JScrollPane

Comment: To elaborate on mkorbel's comment. A LineBorder does only paint a single pixel for the Border. If you see a thicker line it is from the parent component. Change the color of your LineBorder to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it has more to do with using `null` layouts...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestBorder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBorder();
    }

    public TestBorder() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            innerPanel.add(pane);
            panel.add(innerPanel);
            add(panel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [`JComponent#setBorder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29) API:

> Although technically you can set the border on any object that inherits from `JComponent`, the look and feel implementation of many standard Swing components doesn't work well with user-set borders. In general, when you want to set a border on a standard Swing component other than `JPanel` or `JLabel`, we recommend that you put the component in a `JPanel` and set the border on the `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Consult API setBorder method (new EmptyBorder ());

As well as using the variable JTextPane varible.setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.xxx);